# Retrieving data does not import more than one value for each person using SOAP API

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I have an issue where I want to retrieve data using SOAP API. In my main block, I create a DataTable called `ResultsTable` which I create columns for. I then loop through a list of `LocalAPIKey`s and for each key I execute this function:

```
private static DataTable GetPayrollV2(DataTable ResultsTable, string ServerUrl, string LocalAPIKey)
    {
           // Setting up to retrieve data from SOAP API. Removed code. 
           // Get response and return it
           XmlDocument xmlResult = new XmlDocument();
           try
           {
               using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
               {
               StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
               result = reader.ReadToEnd();
               reader.Close();
               }
               xmlResult.LoadXml(result);
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
           }

           XmlNodeList also_calledList = xmlResult.GetElementsByTagName("return");
           XmlNode also_calledElement = also_calledList[0];
           XmlNodeList titleList = also_calledElement.ChildNodes;

           foreach (XmlNode titleNode in titleList)
           {
               if (titleNode != null)
               {
                   DataRow row = ResultsTable.NewRow();
                   row["StoreKey"] = titleNode["costCentre"].InnerText;  // Error after edit, System.NullReferenceException
                   row["EmployeeName"] = titleNode["empName"].InnerText;
                   row["DateKey"] = titleNode["date"].InnerText;
                   row["Incheck"] = titleNode["in"].InnerText;
                   row["Outcheck"] = titleNode["out"].InnerText;
                   ResultsTable.Rows.Add(row);
                   return ResultsTable;
               }
           }
        return ResultsTable;
     }
```

which I simply want to add a row to the existing DataTable (later on in the code, I copy the whole DataTable using SqlBulkCopy into a SQL Database).

My issue is that when I run my example Query in SOAP UI I get the following output:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:tns="https://serverURL">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:wsdlGetValuesResponse xmlns:ns1="uri:Values">
         <return xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:PayrollV2[14]">
            <item xsi:type="tns:PayrollV2">
               <empName xsi:type="xsd:string">Doe, John</empName>
               <badgeNo xsi:type="xsd:string">3761</badgeNo>
               <date xsi:type="xsd:date">2017-03-30</date>
               <in xsi:type="xsd:string">18:15</in>
               <out xsi:type="xsd:string">20:00</out>
               <costCentre xsi:type="xsd:string">6002</costCentre>
            </item>
            <item xsi:type="tns:PayrollV2">
               <empName xsi:type="xsd:string">Doe, John</empName>
               <badgeNo xsi:type="xsd:string">3761</badgeNo>
               <date xsi:type="xsd:date">2017-03-30</date>
               <in xsi:type="xsd:string">20:00</in>
               <out xsi:type="xsd:string">21:00</out>
               <costCentre xsi:type="xsd:string">6002</costCentre>
            </item>
            <item xsi:type="tns:PayrollV2">
               <empName xsi:type="xsd:string">Doe, John</empName>
               <badgeNo xsi:type="xsd:string">3761</badgeNo>
               <date xsi:type="xsd:date">2017-03-30</date>
               <in xsi:type="xsd:string">21:15</in>
               <out xsi:type="xsd:string">22:00</out>
               <costCentre xsi:type="xsd:string">6002</costCentre>
            </item>
         </return>
      </ns1:wsdlGetValuesResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

but when I've ran my script, there are no errors however the resulting table in SQL has only one row of data of `John Doe`, the entry from which he checked in `18:15` and out `20:00` of the thirtiest of march, the rest are gone.

The Table `ResultsTable` also only contain 1 entry of each name. Thus, even if people have worked on both the 30:th and the 31:st, only one entry is returned in total.

Does anyone have any idea why I wont get the whole output from SOAP UI?

> EDIT

I altered the code by modifying:

```
XmlNodeList also_calledList = xmlResult.GetElementsByTagName("return");
```

into

```
 XmlNodeList also_calledList = xmlResult.GetElementsByTagName("item");
```

This change appeared to pan out OK. When I inspect `also_calledList` it seems to return the values I want, i.e. multiple incheck times for the same employee and date.

This however caused an error which caused the program to not be able to proceed about a `NullReference` at the row which I have commented in the code.

> EDIT 2

I noticed that the titleList has the following appearence when I inspect it using `Quick View`:

[image: Quick View of titleList]

From further testing I've noticed that only the XmlElement [0] is returned to the DataTable. How can I "Catch" the data of the remaining 14?

I tried to do:

```
foreach (XmlElement _ in titleList)
{
    foreach (XmlNode titleNode in titleList)
    {
        if (titleNode != null && titleNode.InnerText != null)
        {
           DataRow row = ResultsTable.NewRow();
           row["StoreKey"] = titleNode["costCentre"].InnerText;  
           row["EmployeeName"] = titleNode["empName"].InnerText;
           row["DateKey"] = titleNode["date"].InnerText;
           row["Incheck"] = titleNode["in"].InnerText;
           row["Outcheck"] = titleNode["out"].InnerText;
           ResultsTable.Rows.Add(row);
           return ResultsTable;
          }
    }
}
```

but that returned the same output.

I've also tried to use the original Query, but loop using

```
  foreach (XmlNode titleNode in titleList[1])
  {
         \\ same after this
  }
```

but this returned an empty data table. My thought was to be able to iterate using some kind of recursion of `... in titleList[i]` where i would be a loop from 0 to the amount of elements returned.

Comment: Use the wsdl luke.... seriously dont build your XML by hand use a WSDL import function and let C# create the objects for you.

Comment: @Namphibian    Thanks for replying! I'll check into that during the day. I am not sure if I were provided a wsdl URL. I am using a SDK myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a simple program to parse your Xml

```
public static PayrollItem[] GetPayrollItems(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
{
    var items = new List<PayrollItem>();

    var node = xmlDoc.FirstChild; //SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    if (node != null)
    {
        node = node.FirstChild; //SOAP-ENV:Body
        if (node != null)
        {
            node = node.FirstChild; //ns1:wsdlGetValuesResponse
            if (node != null)
            {
                node = node.FirstChild;  //return

                if (node != null)
                {
                    int count = node.ChildNodes.Count;

                    foreach (XmlNode nodeItem in node.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        PayrollItem item = new PayrollItem();

                        item.EmpName = nodeItem["empName"].InnerText;
                        item.BadgeNo = nodeItem["badgeNo"].InnerText;
                        item.CostCentre = nodeItem["costCentre"].InnerText;
                        item.Date = nodeItem["date"].InnerText;
                        item.In = nodeItem["in"].InnerText;
                        item.Out = nodeItem["out"].InnerText;

                        items.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return items.ToArray();
}
```

Here `PayrollItem` is a simple data Class to hold the values

```
class PayrollItem
{
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public string BadgeNo { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string In { get; set; }
    public string Out { get; set; }
    public string CostCentre { get; set; }
}
```

Once you have your Xml converted to an object, you can use this object to populate your `DataRow`

The logic in the program is very simple. I just used the `.FirstChild` property to navigate the Xml to reach the relevant node.

Currently all the elements are treated as `string`. You can change it to appropriate data type and use it in subsequent processing.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'll investigate this solution during the day. Initial testing showed an error on the line `var items = new List<PayrollItem>();` about `List<PayrollItem>` not being a type that could be bound.

Comment: Figured the above error out. I needed to add `using System.Collections.Generic` to the top. Now I have the error on the row `items.add(item);` that `List<PayrollItem> does not contain a definition for add no extension method add accepting a first argument of type List<PayrollItem> could be found`. Trying to solve this at the moment

Comment: Resolved the above issue as well. Need to go now however so can't test anything. Just commented to avoid you starting to perhaps modify a code which I have working.